# Functions as arguments in gnuplot

Tags: function, recursion, gnuplot, higher-order-functions

In gnuplot, is there a way to pass a user defined function as an argument to another user defined function?  For example, I can write a function loop which will sum shifts of a given function:

```
f(x) = (x <= 0) ? 0 : 1/(1+x)**2
loop(x, i, s) = (i == 0) ? f(x) : loop(x-s, i-1, s) + f(x)
```

Then I can do things like:

```
plot loop(x, 10, 1)
```

But, how do I define a function loop2 that does this for any function, as in something like:

```
loop2(g, x, i, s) = (i == 0) ? g(x) : loop2(g, x-s, i-1, s) + g(x)
```

so that I can then do things like:

```
f3(x) = (x <= 0) ? 0 : 1/(1+x)**3
plot loop2(f, x, 10, 1)
replot loop2(f3, x, 10, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible in gnuplot 5.4.

The development version (gnuplot 5.5) has recently gained the ability to label a block of text commands as a named executable function, known as a "function block".  This gives you access to commands in a function block that are not possible in a one-line user defined function.  Here is your example run in a recent build of the development version. At the top level the *name* of the function ("f" or "f3") is passed as a parameter that can be used to construct a call of the function itself.

```
function $loop2(name, x, i, s) << EOF
  local temp = 0
  eval sprintf("temp = %s(x)", name)
  return (i == 0) ? temp : temp + $loop2(name, x-s, i-1, s)
EOF

f(x) = (x <= 0) ? 0 : 1/(1+x)**2
f3(x) = (x <= 0) ? 0 : 1/(1+x)**3  

set key left Left reverse
set tics nomirror
set border 3
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:1.5]

plot $loop2("f", x, 10, 1), $loop2("f3", x, 10, 1)
```

[image]

And here is a link to an example in the demo collection that illustrates calling one function block from another, wrapping both in a top-level user defined function.
[function_block demo](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.5/function_block.html)

Comment: Thanks for the information.  It's a shame that one cannot pass a function in as an argument without resorting to a function block that uses eval and sprintf.

Comment: I imagine it would be possible to make this work;  I will forward it as a "feature request".